# printf columns of different widths and newline

Tags: bash, printf

How would I specify different column widths and a new line at end using printf?

for example: <---Col A---> <-----------------Col B-----------------> <-Col C->

I have broken down to trying to do individual printf statements like this:

```
printf "%-20s" $COLA && printf "%-14s" $COLB
```

This must not be right though... Also for a newline I have been appending echo "" which I know is not right...

```
printf "%-20s" $COLA && printf "%-14s" $COLB && echo ""
```

There is sooooooooooooo much wrong with everything here, but I am very new to printf

I know /n will line break, but it was breaking up all the fields in a single row to new lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combine the statements

```
printf '%-20s%-14s%s\n' 'Col A' 'Col B' 'Col C'
```

Result

```
Col A               Col B         Col C
```

Answer (score 0):

```
printf "%-20s %-14s %s\n" "$COLA" "$COLB" "$COLC"
```

If there are more arguments than there are conversion specifications, then `printf` starts back at the beginning of the format string when it runs out.  However, the call above ensures that even if there are spaces in `$COLA`, `$COLB` or `$COLC`, this will format the data as expected (or, at least, as I think would be expected).